Covariance Matrix Regularization
Suppose the sample covariance matrix $\hat{\Sigma}$ is singular. One can make it a positive definite matrix by adding a scalar $\lambda>0$ multiple of identity matrix to that, i.e. $\tilde{\Sigma}=\hat{\Sigma}+\lambda I_p$. Theoretically, $\tilde{\Sigma}$ is positive definite (p.d.) for any $\lambda>0$. Is it correct?
However, in references it is said that it is p.d. for “some” $\lambda>0$. Is that because of practical and computational reasons?
Thanks in advance for your help!

You are right, if a matrix $B$ is positive semidefinite, then $B+\lambda I$ is positive definite for all positive $\lambda$.
It could be due to

numerically issue
the paper is describing the scenario for arbitrary matrix, in this case, for indefinite matrix, it only holds for some positive $\lambda$.
or the author being not as precise.


Thank you, Siong for sharing your thoughts on this. The scenario is actually for the high-dimensional settings where dimension (p) > sample size (n) for which the sample covariance matrix is singular. Is it possible for it to have negative eigenvalues? As far as I know, sample covariance matrix is positive semidefinite.

you are right, sample covariance matrix is positive semidefinite. Numerically sometimes $0$ might be represented by a small negative number but ya, theoretically it should be positive semidefinite.
